# Ignore Fuzzy Grouping for certain words

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence

I am creating an SSIS Package for finding similar customers in two different databases.
I have created a union all using Fuzzy Grouping and I have set the threshold to 85 and above.

Most of the Results seems accurate, however there is one such as Blink and Bling which is coming at 0.88 similarity. Is there a way I an add a specification to Ignore this within the SSIS without me changing the similarity threshold?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your question with sample data. here is what i got with threshold of .75

[image]

Can you do the given steps and whether it helps you.

1. Add a conditional split before the Fuzzy Grouping.
2. Write conditions in the conditional split for your required/ identified cases.
   so that those records bypass the Fuzzy Grouping
3. Use a union all after the Fuzzy Grouping.

May be like this.

[image]

I am not sure, whether this is what you are looking for. But you can use conditional split to split your data flow.